# Построить график ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Я хочу построить график сравнения двух численных переменных, представленных как среднее и стандартное отклонение по оси Х по двум группам. Например в левой части значения числового показателя по двум группам до операции, а справа значения того же показателя после операции? По оси Y - значения показателя. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас интересует `geom_errorbar`. Можно и составить самостоятельно с `geom_point` и `geom_segment`.
Для размещения рядом статистик по двум группам есть параметр `nudge`.
Также может быть полезен [мой недавний пост](https://ikashnitsky.github.io/2019/dotplot/), воспроизводящий эту картинку:
[image]
<sub>(источник: [github.io](https://ikashnitsky.github.io/images/190719/one-figure.png))</sub>

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Очень своевременная помощь!